# How can I automatically shutdown the system after a specific time?

Tags: shutdown, automation

How can I automatically shutdown the system after a certain customizable time?

Comment: This graphical script can be useful https://askubuntu.com/questions/640845/what-graphical-utility-can-i-use-for-ubuntu-auto-shutdown

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Open a terminal window and type in:

```
sudo shutdown -h +60
```

and just replace 60 with whatever number of minutes you want to take.

More info here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-473173.html
http://www.linux.org/lessons/beginner/l5/lesson5a.html

Comment: The `-P` parameter (power off) seems to be a good idea too.

Comment: shutdown +m 60 doesn't work for me. gives me an error message and says that there's an invalid time value.

Comment: I thought it was odd... it shouldn't be "+m 60", it should be "+60" (or maybe more like "-h +60". The bottom of this page seems to know how it works: http://www.linux.org/lessons/beginner/l5/lesson5a.html.

Comment: "shutdown -P 1" - works well and shuts down the system in 1 minute, no time unit needed.

Comment: actually its sudo ..... because need root privileges

Answer (score 9):

- You can use [**gshutdown** [image: Install gshutdown]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gshutdown)
- After installation it can be found under Applications → Accessories → GShutdown
  [image]
- Also have a look at this **[method](http://www.ohbuntu.blogspot.com/2010/01/auto-shutdown-timer.html)**.

Comment: Can anyone say me why they down vote?

Comment: i didn't down vote. But Gshutdown doesn't work smoothly here. When i choose shutdown it insteads log the user out?

Comment: Me too, it logs the user out and the laptop goes to sleep mode

Answer (score 4):

Because the topic abt shutting down PC after **certain period of inactivity** is *redirected* to this topic, I will explain this issue here.

I spent lots of time to solve this problem, so I find it useful to share it, to make the same issue simple for others. I hv tried different programmes but they haven't work for me so I found using **short script** with **cronjob** the best solution.

Firstly I refered to post [Timed Shutdown - shutdown after 30 minutes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346924/timed-shutdown-shutdown-after-30-minutes/346955#346955)

I will copy it below and then explain improvements to make it work:

> Install xprintidle. This tool gives the idle time of a user.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install xprintidle
> ```
>
> Make a script autoshutdown.sh which checks for the idle time and
>   instructs the computer to shutdown if idle for 30 minutes.
>
> ```
> idle=$(xprintidle)
>
> if [ $idle -gt 1800000 ]; then
>     shutdown -h now
> fi
> ```
>
> Make a cronjob for this that checks from time to time if the system
>   has been idle for too long and if it has been idle for a longer than
>   30 minutes it will shutdown. Note that the cronjob has to be made for
>   the root user.

---

This script needs some improvements to work, like:

```
idle=`env DISPLAY=:0 su OUR_USER -c xprintidle 2>&1`
```

`OUR_USER` is the user we refer to for checking idle time (not root user)

`DISPLAY=:0` is correct for one desktop display (run `env` command to read `DISPLAY` in your situation)

if script is run by `OUR_USER`, line above can be reduced:

```
idle=`env DISPLAY=:0 xprintidle 2>&1`
```

This topic is described http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1069602

if script is run by `OUR_USER`, `shutdown` command should be preceded by `sudo`

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

---

My script was run from cron by line in cron file:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/OUR_USER/autoshutdown.sh
```

- every 5 minutes
- OUR_USER should be replaced as earlier to the user we refer to.

---

If script is not run by root we should remember to add the line:

```
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

in **sudoers** file, so *shutdown* command won't need a password to be executed.

---

I tried such cronjobs on 2 similar distro **Lubuntu 12.04.4 RC LXLE 32-bit** ( http://www.lxle.net/ )

In one system it works only using root cronjob set in file:

/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root

---

### CAVEAT

Another problem is that **xprintidle in my system has given sometimes random for me values** and sometimes logically incremental. The final result - my system has been usually shutdown after 20 mins maybe, if I set the max idle value to 30 mins. I think the culprit is **xscreensaver** which doesn't work as is set by entered parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

ComplexShutdown
https://launchpad.net/complexshutdown

or EasyShutdown
https://launchpad.net/easyshutdown

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sleep` for that. They're used to delay/ pause an operation. Combine that with `shutdown` you get a power off timer.
Example to sleep after 1 hour:

```
sleep 3600 && sudo shutdown now
```

You can use math as well, here's to power off after 3 hour:

```
sleep $((3600*3)) && sudo shutdown now
```

Answer (score 0):

Crontab seemed like the perfect and most convenient solution for a scheduled shutdown.

But I could not get it running for quite a while using (as supplied by Chat):

```
crontab -e
30 22 * * * /sbin/shutdown -h now
```

My solution was to create a crontab, but as superuser. Makes sense, dont want any old bod shutting down the server.

```
sudo crontab -e -u root
```

Then add PW,select text editor

Then:

```
30 22 * * * /sbin/shutdown -h now
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Shutdown Timer, a GNOME Shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4372/shutdowntimer/).
[An old version for older GNOME version](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/792/shutdowntimer/) is still available.

To be able to use GNOME Extension, type into a terminal:

```
sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell gnome-shell-extension-prefs
```