# Shutdown after idle (but not if the SAMBA server is in use)

Tags: command-line, suspend, shutdown, schedule, idle

I have found several questions about this, but I can't seem to find one that suits my needs.

I'd like my machine (Xubuntu 16.04) to power-off if I'm not using it for 30 minutes. However, I use it to stream videos to my media center (through a SAMBA server), so I don't want it to shut down in that case.

All the answers I've found ignore network activity and only focus on keystrokes and mouse moves.

Comment: Wait, do you want to shutdown or suspend (looking at your own answer)?

Comment: Originally I wanted to shutdown, but I don't care too much either way. I have updated my answer so that anyone can adapt it to shutdown or suspend at will :)

Comment: Hi user, any luck in trying? I'd appreciate a comment in any direction.

Comment: I haven't forgotten about this, but I've been busy with other stuff and got my solution to work, so I haven't looked much into this still, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set up my own cron job to deal with this.

## **What I achieved**

Suspending/shutting down the machine if it has been idle (no keystrokes or mouse moves) for a certain amount of time, unless there are files being accessed in its SAMBA server.

## **Requirements**

- `root` access.
- `xprintidle` (install it by executing in a terminal: `sudo apt-get install xprintidle`)

## **How to**

1. Save the following script in a location of your choice (in my case, `/home/user/.useful-scripts/idle.sh`):

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   # Checks the time the computer has been idle (no keystrokes or mouse moves)
   # If it's greater than the set limit, it will suspend the machine if no
   # files are being accessed through the SAMBA server.


   # The maximum number of milliseconds the computer is allowed to be idle before
   # it is suspended (set to 20 minutes)
   IDLE_LIMIT_MS=1200000

   # How long the machine has been idle for
   IDLE_TIME_MS=$(/sbin/runuser -l ic -c "DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/xprintidle")

   if [ $IDLE_TIME_MS -gt $IDLE_LIMIT_MS ] ;
   then
       # If there are no files locked by SAMBA, suspend the machine
       FILES_LOCKED=$(/usr/bin/smbstatus | /bin/grep 'Locked files:')

       if [[ -z "${FILES_LOCKED}" ]] ;
       then
           /bin/systemctl suspend -i
           # If you prefer to shut down instead of suspend, comment the
           # previous line and uncomment the following one:
           # /sbin/poweroff
       fi
   fi
   ```

   Be aware that this script will be run by `cron`. This has certain implications, but mainly that `DISPLAY` and `PATH` environment variables are not set. Therefore, we need give the full path when invoking a command. The paths might change in your machine, so make sure they match your configuration (for example, to find the path for `xprintidle` execute in a terminal `which xprintidle`).

   We also need to specify the DISPLAY for which we want the `xprintidle`information. It is normally `:0.0`, but you can be sure of that by running `w` from a terminal while logged in and checking the `FROM` column. Read these three links ([1](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1069602), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434522/xprintidle-doesnt-work-in-cronjob-why) and [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117978/script-doesnt-run-via-crontab-but-works-fine-standalone)) for more information about `PATH` and `DISPLAY` under `cron`.
2. Make sure you make it executable:

   > chmod +x /home/user/.useful-scripts/idle.sh
3. Set up the job to run periodically using [`cron`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html). `smbstatus` requires to be run as `root`, so we need to invoke `crontab` using `sudo`:

   > sudo crontab -e

   Add the following line to run the script periodically:

   > * * * * * /home/user/.useful-scripts/idle.sh

   This sets up a cron job to run every minute and execute our script. You can set up the periodicity to a higher value if you don't care about smaller precision (see [this link](http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm) for more information on the necessary syntax).

This is it. `cron` will check the idle state of the machine every minute, and if it has been idle for more than 20 minutes (can be adjusted with the `IDLE_LIMIT_MS` variable) it will make sure that no files are being accessed through the SAMBA server; in that case, it will suspend the machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the (very low on juice) background script, which will suspend the computer, rounded on 10 seconds:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
import subprocess

# --- set idle time below (seconds)
idle_set = 1200
# ---

def get_packets():
    return int([l.strip().split()[1].replace("packets:", "") for l in \
            subprocess.check_output("ifconfig").decode("utf-8").splitlines()\
            if " RX " in l][0])

def get_idle():
    return int(int(subprocess.check_output("xprintidle").decode("utf-8").strip())/1000)

data1 = get_packets()
t = 0

while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    data2 = get_packets()
    if data2 - data1 > 3000:
        t = 0
    else:
        t += 10
    idletime = get_idle()
    if all([idletime > idle_set, t > idle_set]):
        subprocess.Popen(["systemctl", "suspend", "-i"])
    data1 = data2
```

#### What it does

- Once per 10 seconds, it checks the current *received* amount of data, comparing it with 10 seconds ago (using `ifconfig`). If it exceeds a certain amount, the "counter" is set to zero, else a0 seconds is added to the "stream" -idle time.
- Also once per 10 seconds it looks at the "general" idle-time, using `xprintidle`

If both exceed the set time (in the head of the script), the computer is put to sleep.

#### How to set up

1. The script needs `xprintidle`

   ```
   sudo apt-get xprintidle
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `set_idle.py`
3. In the head section of the script, set the desired idle time
4. Test- rfun it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/set_idle.py
   ```

If all works fine, add it to Startup Applications.

#### Note

This answer assumes traffic is via Ethernet connection. If not, the function `get_packets()` possibly needs a small edit.

Comment: Thanks! The script seems to succeed in doing what it wants to do, but I'm not sure it is what I need. When streaming content, it is not the amount of packets received but the amount of packets sent that should be monitored. Also, 3000 is a bit of a magic constant.
The idea seems to be good to send the computer to sleep if it is not downloading stuff,  though.