# Automatic shutdown at specified times?

Tags: shutdown, cron, kiosk

I'm aware I can use (sudo?) `shutdown -h hh:mm` in a terminal window to shut down a system, however the user that is logged in is a kiosk user, which is locked down in such a way that terminal (or any window other than firefox, for that matter) cannot be opened.

My question is:
Is there a way I can do this without having a terminal window opened? I've read about cron, but can't quite work it out.
How can I change the shutoff time depending on what day it is?

Comment: Do you want to shutdown in 02:00 AM?

Comment: No, sorry, that was just what was used in the example I read. Usually at 11:30, but I was wondering if there is a way to specify different times for different days?

Comment: You can refer the url for automatic shutdown. http://askubuntu.com/questions/19774/how-can-i-automatically-shutdown-the-system-after-a-specific-time

Comment: @vembutech That question is for shutting down *after* a certain time period has passed - not shutting down *at* a certain time - however although it would be easy to adopt this to my needs, I still can't run additional windows other than firefox. Thank you for your reply though! It seems much simpler than using cron, and I will most likely use it for other uses :)

Comment: @MrAxlee... So, you want the system to shut down *n* hours after turning on?

Comment: @Whaaaaaat Nono, other way around :P The question vembutech linked is how to shut down *n* hours after turning on, which can be modified to suit my needs but I still cannot run additional windows (like terminal, or [gShutdown](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gshutdown) which was linked to as an answer.  

Trying to decide which cron answer would be best to mark as a solution!

Comment: you don't need additional tools if you want the system to shut down after some time.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Cron will work very well for this.

You need first to find the complete path to the shutdown command:

```
a@ubuntu:~$ which shutdown
/usr/sbin/shutdown
```

Knowing the path to the `shutdown` command, you can add the below line (with tweaks) to the end of `/etc/crontab`:

```
30 23 * * * root /usr/sbin/shutdown -h now
```

At 23:30 (11:30 PM), the kiosk will shut down. No matter what user is logged in, the shutdown command runs as root.

(If you don't want to use the global crontab, log in as root and use `crontab -e`.  Use the same above syntax without the `root`).

---

Cron Format:

```
MM HH DD OO WW command
```

`MM`: Minute, 0-59
`HH`: 24-hour hour
`DD`: Day of month
`OO`: Month
`WW`: Day of Week (Sunday is 0, Monday is 1)
`command`: Self-explanatory

Comment: @JacobVlijm When was that added? I don't see it in the official [Cron docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).

Comment: I'll look it up...

Comment: from crontab(5): *The format of the system crontab, /etc/crontab includes a who column which does not exist in user crontabs. In the system crontab, cron runs the command as the user specified in this column. In a user crontab, all commands run as the user who created the crontab.*

Comment: @Whaaaaaat Great answer, works perfectly, thanks!. What's the difference between `-h` and `-s`?

Comment: @MrAxlee `-s` doesn't seem to be "proper syntax." `-h` means to **halt or shutdown the system** (system's choice - shutdown preferred)

Comment: if you're on mac you need to specify the full path /sbin/shutdown since the PATH for crontab on mac only contains /usr/bin:/bin

Comment: Why do you need root for this? I mean user can power off the system, use of user’s CEO tab should be enough, no?

Answer (score 11):

A cronjob seems to be the best way because you can specify different times for different days. 
On Gnome based systems you can just install [GNOME Shedule](http://gnome-schedule.sourceforge.net/) Tasks  by using

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule
```

and then configure the cronjob using the GUI.

otherwise you would have to use `sudo crontab -e` and then add the following lines

```
30 11 * * 1-5 /sbin/shutdown -h now
30 10 * * 0,6 /sbin/shutdown -h now
```

this would shutdown the PC at 11:30 from Monday to Friday and on 10:30 on Saturday and Sunday.
The structure is very simple:

```
minute (0-59), hour (0-23, 0 = midnight), day (1-31), month (1-12), weekday (0-6, 0 = Sunday), command
```

For more information about this you could also just check out [CronHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

Comment: I had to specifically use `/sbin/shutdown` instead of `shutdown` because my root cron PATH was different than in the terminal I tried my script.

Comment: @Jaakko That's still true with Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 6):

We can shutdown automatically at specified time by simply running command `sudo poweroff` in `crontab`.

If you want to shutdown the system at 6:30 pm everyday. Type in terminal:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

edit

```
30 18 * * * poweroff
```

Comment: @mrm There are alternative methods, there could be many different solutions to particular issue and the answers so. Isn't it answer useful or not? Please I request you not to downvote to answer or question if you're not clear about it. Read question properly and see if the answer apply to that specific question or not. If you still have any dilemma you are free to ask on  [Ask Ubuntu Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/) or here and then make a decision.

Comment: In one crontab line, you've got two issues: `poweroff` skips shutdown scripts, which may be important to, say, safely shutdown your database or whatever, and you've got a `sudo` in a root crontab which is unneeded. You also didn't address how to reference different days of the week as the question asked. So no, this isn't an alternative method. As is, it's two mistakes and an omission. The two other answers made a year prior to yours are correct and actually work.

Comment: @mrm Well, I'm using this script for last three years and I didn't see any issue. And yes this [alternative](https://askubuntu.com/questions/578144/why-doesnt-running-sudo-shutdown-now-shut-down#578155) and also correct useful method. Que is Automatic shutdown at specified times. There is a [command to shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187071/how-do-i-shut-down-or-reboot-from-a-terminal/187072#187080) and for auto specified time, we can use crontab as per our requirement. It would be better for you if you ask a different question regarding your issue.

Comment: Straightforward solution. Has been running for 8 days, no issues.