# Cron job. Runs at minutes interval but otherwise when set at another time

Tags: cron

During the test of my script.

The cronjob should run a script through the browser every 2 minutes. So I had the following cron:

```
*/2 * * * * wget -O http://192.10.10.1/mypage/myscript.php
```

The cron run a couple of times before I changed it to:

```
0 1 * * * wget -O http://192.10.10.1/mypage/myscript.php
```

to run the script everyday at 1am but it does not work.

I am a bit confused why the first one successfully run my script while the latter didn't. What am I doing wrong? Or what could possibly be the reason why running it at 1am does not work?

Comment: Are you running your `cron` editing as `crontab -e` as your normal user?

Comment: @Terrance By normal user do you mean root? If yes, then no, I am logged in as another user and used `crontab -e`

Comment: No, I didn't mean root, so you should be fine.   If you run `which wget`, does it return `/usr/bin/wget`?  If it does, check your crontab environment by adding a line to it that says `* * * * * env > /home/<username>/env_dump.txt` so that you can see what the environment is set to.  Hopefully the `/usr/bin` is in your path environment.  Remove the line from crontab after 1 minute.  It will create the file.

Comment: Your line looks like it should work fine though.

Comment: I believe it's fine too. Though it confuses me that when it is ran every two minutes it works fine but when I set it at 1am it does not work. Does it affect that I have my terminal turned off at that time? (Sorry. I'm a noob at Linux)

Comment: The computer itself would have to stay on at that time.   You could set up a crontab job to turn off the computer at a specified time after that one is supposed to run.  See here:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/567955/automatic-shutdown-at-specified-times

Comment: To me, the -O option to wget is missing a filename. If I try this command in a terminal I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in a comment above, the most obvious pbm is that you are not using the `-O` option correctly.

Look up  `man wget` in terminal. Here is an extract:

> `-O file`
>  `--output-document=file`. 
>  The documents will not be
>   written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated
>   together and written to "file".  If `-` is used as file, documents
>   will be printed to standard output (stdout), disabling link conversion.
>   Use `./-` to print to a file literally named `-`.
>  Use of `-O` is
>   analogous to shell redirection:
>   `wget -O file http://foo` is
>   intended to work like `wget -O - http://foo > file`; where "file" will be
>   truncated immediately, and all downloaded content will be written
>   there.

If, **as a non root user**, you run a GUI cmd or direct yr output to `stdout` *in an already running X session*, make sure yr [`cron` environment knows about the active display](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68054/xdotool-using-display-0-not-works-in-crontab). To make `cron` GUI aware, i.e. to tell it, what display the program should use (`:0` is the default in a desktop environment)

```
0 1 * * * export DISPLAY=:0; XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority /usr/bin/wget -O - http://192.10.10.1/mypage/myscript.php
```

or, if you want to set the DISPLAY environment variable *ONLY* for a specific cmd:

```
0 1 * * * DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority /usr/bin/wget -O - http://192.10.10.1/mypage/myscript.php
```

or, if redirecting output to a file for later perusal, the need to specify the correct display disappears because nothing actually goes to `stdout` :

```
0 1 * * *  /usr/bin/wget -O <filename> http://192.10.10.1/mypage/myscript.php
```

The latter solution makes more sense, if you run yr cron job at 1am and you are not sitting in front of yr desktop display.

==
Let us known in case of continuing problems.