# What graphical utility can I use for Ubuntu auto shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, hibernate

In Microsoft Windows I use `switch off` software for auto shutdown, Hibernate, restart etc. Can I find something similar in Ubuntu?

[image: switch off]

I read following link. [How can I automatically shutdown the system after a specific time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19774/how-can-i-automatically-shutdown-the-system-after-a-specific-time)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GShutdown](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/gshutdown/) is a utility which allows you to schedule the shutdown or restart of your computer. With it you can simply and quickly choose the turn off time at either a specific time or after a countdown.

#### Install Gshutdown:

```
sudo apt-get install gshutdown
```

[image]

[source.](http://ubuntuguide.net/gshutdown-gui-tool-for-scheduled-shutdownrestart-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

For some unknown reason this sorts of applications don't last for long and they are broken on newer iterations of Ubuntu. *Gshutdown* didn't work out of the box for Ubuntu 15.10 and it's not very convenient to download a couple of hundreds MB of dependencies for kwin application. At least not for this kind of application.

Here's a little script I wrote that issues this problem and arguably it is a better choice. Why :

- it is a graphical script so it can be run as classic application
- as any other script features can be adjusted to user's preference
- the code can be used in various distros and it's not probable that will change any time soon
- various options included are described in script.

*Shutdown dialog* in action:
[image]

### How to use it

There is only one package that needs to be installed which addresses *user inactivity* feature, however script will run other available options well without it. To install 'xprintidle' type in terminal:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install xprintidle
```

Open text editor, paste the code provided below and save the file as `Shutdown_dialog` in your home folder. Right click on file and select `allow executing file as program` or via terminal:

```bsh
chmod +x ~/Shutdown_dialog
```

The code:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

###########<<INFO
# This script is intended for use in various Linux distros. In order to use all available options install 'xprintidle' package. It is responsible for 'system idle' option,
# but the script will run without it as well. To install package on Debian-based distros execute: `sudo apt-get install xprintidle` .
# Other packages used in script: zenity, notifyOSD, xdotool, wmctrl, play.
#
# Below INFO section there are some predefined variables. Their values can easily be customized by user.
#
#   Some options available:
#   
# -Select an action - the only option that must be selected, others can omit. The hibernation action is not visible by default, but it can be enabled. Use this at your own risk,
# it has not been tested. To enable hibernation uncomment two lines in `case var1` statement and add |Hibernate option in zenity dialogs:
#  --list-values='Shutdown|Restart|Hibernate|Suspend|Logout|Lock screen'. Alternative actions are commented and use them in case your distro doesn't support default ones.
#
# -Time from now; on user inactivity; at specific time and date - only one of these can be used at the same time. The accuracy for latter two is +-1 min.
#
# -Run custom command before action executes - BE CAREFULL !!! with this one. After confirmation dialog timeout, there is no turning back.
#
# -When selected application exit - clicking on this option new dialog will be presented with available options. Select action and preferred options (if any) and press OK. 
# Then select the application by clicking on it.
#
# -Default - first time this option is activated it will open new dialog with available options. Select preferred options. They will be saved in `default_conf_file` 
# which is predefined as    `default_conf_file=~/.cache/Shutdown_dialog_conf_file.txt`  The script will then execute ! 
# But on next run script will execute just by pressing `default` button.
#############INFO

#####Predefined variables intended for user customization
default_conf_file=~/.cache/Shutdown_dialog_conf_file.txt
default_sound_1=/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/service-login.oga
default_sound_2=/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/dialog-warning.oga
default_sound_3=/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/message.oga
defaul_time_to_show_confirmation_dialog=10


#####Functions that correspond to selected options
default_option () {
    if [ -f "$default_conf_file" ];then
        options=$(cat "$default_conf_file")
    else
options=$(zenity --forms --title="Reappeared shutdown dialog" --text="\nYou are running DEFAULT option for the first time. Choose settings\n and press OK. The default options will be saved for further use.\n\n *Only one of the marked options can be used at the same time\n" --add-list="Select an action:" --list-values='Shutdown|Restart|Suspend|Logout|Lock screen' --add-entry="Time from now (min)*:" --add-entry="On user inactivity (min)*:" --add-entry="At specific time (hh:mm) and date:*" --add-combo="This has no purpose. It only replaces calendar" --combo-values= --forms-date-format=%Y-%m-%d --add-entry="Run command before action executes:" --add-entry="Show desktop notifications every (min):" --add-entry="Seconds to display confirmation dialog:" --add-combo="Play sound on confirmation dialog:" --combo-values="|default_sound_1|default_sound_2|default_sound_3")
        [ $? == 1 ] && exit 1
        echo "$options" > "$default_conf_file"
        rm_default_conf_file="$default_conf_file"
    fi  
}



select_app () {
options=$(zenity --forms --title="Reappeared shutdown dialog" --text="\n You are running WHEN SELECTED APPLICATION EXIT option! \n\n Choose additional settings, press OK and then click on application\n to select. Use Alt+Tab to cycle through open applications.\n\n" --add-list="Select an action:" --list-values='Shutdown|Restart|Suspend|Logout|Lock screen' --add-combo="Unavailable option" --combo-values= --add-combo="Unavailable option" --combo-values= --add-combo="Unavailable option" --combo-values= --add-combo="Unavailable option" --combo-values= --add-entry="Run command before action executes:" --add-combo="Unavailable option" --combo-values= --add-entry="Seconds to display confirmation dialog:" --add-combo="Play sound on confirmation dialog:" --combo-values="|default_sound_1|default_sound_2|default_sound_3")
    [ $? == 1 ] && exit 1
    win_id=$(xdotool selectwindow)
    notify-send "Window selected:  $(xdotool getwindowname $win_id)"
    win_id=$(printf 0x0%x "$win_id")
    while :
    do
        [[ -z $(wmctrl -l | grep "$win_id") ]] && break || sleep 5
    done
}



user_inactivity () {
    which xprintidle
    if [ $? == 1 ];then
        zenity --warning --timeout=7 --ellipsize --text="\tPackage 'xprintidle' is not installed.\n\n Option ** \"ON USER INACTIVITY\" ** cannot be used!\n\n\t\t Exiting...."
        [ -f "$rm_default_conf_file" ] && rm "$default_conf_file"
        exit 1
    fi
    while [[ "$idle_time" -lt "$var3" ]]
    do
        idle_time=$(( $(xprintidle) / 60000 ))
        sleep 5
    done
}



notification () {
    x=1
    [ -z "$time" ] && return 1
    notify-send "System will $var1 in $time minutes!"
    while :
    do
        remaining=$(( $time - $x * $var7 ))
        sleep "$var7"m
        notify-send "System will $var1 in $remaining minutes!"
        x=$(( x + 1 ))
        [ "$remaining" -lt "$var7" ] && break
    done
    sleep "$remaining"m
}


#####Confirmation dialog shown before action is executed
confirmation_dialog () {
    [ -n "$sound" ] && play "$sound" &
    $(sleep 0.9;wmctrl -r "Shutdown confirmation dialog" -b add,above) &        #comment this line if you don't want dialog to be above other windows
    zenity --question --title="Shutdown confirmation dialog" --text="System will $var1 in $var8 seconds! \n\nDo you wish to execute?" --ellipsize --timeout="$var8" --cancel-label=Cancel
    [ $? == 1 ] && exit 1

}


###### Initial Shudown dialog window #######
options=$(zenity --forms --title="Shutdown dialog" --text="\nAvailable options are documented in the header of the script\n\n *Only one of the marked options can be used at the same time\n" --add-list="Select an action:" --list-values='Shutdown|Restart|Suspend|Logout|Lock screen' --add-entry="Time from now (min)*:" --add-entry="On user inactivity (min)*:" --add-entry="At specific time (hh:mm) and date:*" --add-calendar="Select date for previous option" --forms-date-format=%Y-%m-%d --add-entry="Run command before action executes:" --add-entry="Show desktop notifications every (min):" --add-entry="Seconds to display confirmation dialog (s):" --add-combo="Play sound on confirmation dialog:" --combo-values="|default_sound_1|default_sound_2|default_sound_3" --extra-button="When selected application exit" --extra-button="Default")

#####Validate selection and call functions
if [ $? != 0 ];then
    if [ "$options" == "When selected application exit" ];then select_app
    elif [ "$options" == "Default" ];then default_option
    else exit 1
    fi
fi

#####Variables assignment
old="$IFS"
IFS="|"
read -r var{1..9} <<< "$(echo "$options")"
IFS="$old"

#####Validate and define time variables
if [ "$var2" != 0 ] && [ -z "$var3" ] && [ -z "$var4" ]; then 
    time="$var2"
elif [ "$vr3" != 0 ] && [ -z "$var2" ] && [ -z "$var4" ]; then
    if [ ! -z "$var7" ];then
        zenity --warning --timeout=7 --ellipsize --text="\nThe *** \"ON USER INACTIVITY\" *** option cannot be used with desktop notifications!\n\n\t\t Exiting...."
        [ -f "$rm_default_conf_file" ] && rm "$default_conf_file"
        exit 1
    fi
    user_inactivity
elif [ "$vr4" != 0 ] && [ -z "$var3" ] && [ -z "$var2" ]; then
    current=$(date +%s)
    target=$(date +%s -d "$var5 $var4")
    time=$(( ($target - $current) / 60 ))
elif [ "$var2" == " " ] && [ "$var3" == " " ] && [ "$var4" == " " ]; then :
else
    zenity --warning --timeout=5 --ellipsize --text="\t*Only one of the marked options can be used at the same time!\n\n\t\t Exiting...."
    [ -f "$rm_default_conf_file" ] && rm "$default_conf_file"
    exit 1  
fi

#####Validate selection and define action (replace it with commented one if it doesn't work)
case $var1 in
    Shutdown,)
        action="poweroff";;                     #"systemctl poweroff"
    Restart,)
        action="reboot";;                       #"systemctl reboot"
#   Hibernate,)
#       action="systemctl hibernate";;
    Suspend,)
        action="systemctl suspend";;
    Logout,)
        action="gnome-session-quit --logout --no-prompt";;      #"pkill -u $USER"
    Lock?screen,)
        action="gnome-screensaver-command -l";;             #"xdotool key Ctrl+Alt+l"
esac

#####Validate other settings
[ -n "$var7" ] && notification

[ -z "$var8" ] && var8="$defaul_time_to_show_confirmation_dialog"

[ "$var9" != 0 ] && case $var9 in
    default_sound_1)
        sound="$default_sound_1";;
    default_sound_2)
        sound="$default_sound_2";;  
    default_sound_3)
        sound="$default_sound_3";;
esac    

#####Execute
[[ -n "$time" && -z "$var7" ]] && sleep "$time"m
confirmation_dialog
eval "$var6"
eval "$action"

exit 0
```

Optionally, you can create desktop icon. Open text editor, paste the code provided below and save the file as `Shutdown_dialog.desktop` in your desktop folder. Right click on file and select `allow executing file as program` or via terminal:

```bsh
chmod +x ~/Desktop/Shutdown_dialog.desktop
```

The code:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Name=Shutdown dialog
Comment=Shutdown dialog script
Terminal=false
Icon=/usr/share/icons/oxygen/64x64/actions/system-shutdown.png
Exec="/home/username/Shutdown_dialog"
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Utility;
Name[en_US]=Shutdown dialog
```

Just make sure that `Exec` line have an absolute path to the script.

If anything is unclear, comment and I will edit if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think GShutdown is the best among this utilities. But to make it work with Ubuntu 15.10 you need to do some trick.

1. install & open gshutdown
2. Edit -> Preferences
3. Select "Custom Command"
4. Click "Turn off the computer" and paste this
   sh -c "dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.PowerOff" boolean:true"